# How to pass property methods as arugments in Python

Tags: python-3.x, methods, properties

First, let's consider this working example using get and set methods for the variable x

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0

    def set_x(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        return self._x

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, set_method):
        self._set_method = set_method

    def set_x(self, x):
        self._set_method(x)

f = Foo()
f.set_x(5)
print(f.get_x())
# Prints 5 
b = Bar(f.set_x)
b.set_x(10)
print(f.get_x())
# Prints 10
```

As you can see I pass the possibility to set the variable x of the instance f of class Foo, to the instance b of class Bar.

Now, I would like to do the same, but with property decorators instead, roughly like this

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, x_property):
        self._x_property = x_property

    def set_x(self, x):
        self.x_property = x

f = Foo()
f.x = 5
print(f.x)
# Prints 5
b = Bar(f.x)
b.set_x(10)
print(f.x)
# Prints 5
```

What happens is that the value 5, instead of the property, gets passed to instance b, meaning that b can't access x in instance f. Is there a nice way to solve this?

I would then also like to do the same thing for the get method. In the first code that requires me to pass both methods, but if there is a way to get the second code to work I would hopefully only have to pass on the property which I then can set and get as a normal variable.

I would really want to use the property decorators or similar as it cleans up my code a lot. I use python 3.5.2.

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, overall?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by accessing the `fset` attribute of `Foo.x`.  Note the use of class-dot notation rather than instance-dot. `fset` takes two arguments: the instance to access and the value to write. Here is a working example

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, x_property):
        self.x_property = x_property

    def set_x(self, foo, value):
        self.x_property(foo, value)

f = Foo()
f.x = 5
print(f.x)
b = Bar(Foo.x.fset)
b.set_x(f, 10)
print(f.x)
```

Notice that we had to pass `f` to `set_x` because we need it to invoke the setter. You could eliminate the `f` param by using `partial` from the `functools` module to bind `f` to the property setter. Pass the `partial` binding in to the constructor of `Bar`.

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, x_property):
        self.x_property = x_property

    def set_x(self, value):
        self.x_property(value)

f = Foo()
b = Bar(partial(Foo.x.fset, f))
b.set_x(10)
print(f.x)
```

It might be wise to rename `x_property` and this point. It is really just a function as far as `Bar` is concerned. It wouldn't have to be a property.